# Multiple 'use' statements because of included file

Tags: php

I have a file with a use statement.
Later in the same file, after some code, I include a file that itself has the same use statement as the containing file.

Is this something that must absolutely be avoided ? Or is it a common practice ?

Comment: Are you designing your own programming language or you need to learn programming?
This is a site where programmers ask questions to other programmers.

Answer (score 0):

The "use"s in included files doesn't changes any "use" statement in the calling file.

Comment: doesn't it call memory consumption in relation to the redundant 'use' ?